# Cloud server stuck on dpkg --configure -a

Tags: 10.10, server, java, dpkg, aws

I have an amazon micro instance which runs one or two things for me. The config is minimal, it mainly acts as a host for a java application and couchdb.

I tried to install curl today and got this message:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

So I ran the command using sudo:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up openjdk-6-jre-headless (6b20-1.9.1-1ubuntu3) ...
```

and it's been hanging there for a looooooong time. Top reports that a java process is using just about all of my CPU. Any ideas what this problem is and how I can fix it? Any ideas on what caused the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You're running into [bug 634487](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-ec2/+bug/634487).

The work arounds are:

- use x86_64 instance type
- stop instance, start as m1.small, dpkg --configure -a, stop, start as
  t1.micro

Comment: I'm not really sure how to start the instance 'as' an m1.small. Can you do that with the web console?